# The argument type 'Future<int?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get data from count as int. When i call function ItemCount.getTotalOrder() it says this error. Please help.

**My separate itemcount class function :**

```
 class ItemCount {
      static final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Orders');
      static Future<int?> getTotalOrder() async {
        final count = await db.get().then((value) {
          return value.docs.length;
        });
        print(count);
        if (count == null) {
          return 0 ;
        } else {
          return count;
        }
      }
    }
```

**Function call where data has datatype as int :**

```
Expanded(
         flex: 2,
         child: _buildTile(
         title: AppString.totalOrders,
         data: ItemCount.getTotalOrder(),
         color: blueColor,
       ),
```

Comment: Data is a int type field?

Comment: yes, i have mentioned

Comment: Are you using any State Management plugin? lIke Getx , Provider, Bloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemCount.getTotalOrder()` is an async function. Which means you need to wait for the future to return data. To do this wrap your widget with a `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: ItemCount.getTotalOrder(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {  //true when the data loading is complete from the async method
      return Expanded(
         flex: 2,
         child: _buildTile(
         title: AppString.totalOrders,
         data: snapshot.data,  //snapshot data contains the data returned from future
         color: blueColor,
       );
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();  //FutureBuilder will be displaying this widget as long as the data returned from future is null (that is, still loading)
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Is there any other method ? Because i have multiple widgets to call after.

Comment: Do you mean something like a Listview? In that case you can wrap that widget with FutureBuilder as well. It's best that you use a proper state management technique for this. But if you need a speedy solution, I suggest you wrap your whole widget (the one containing the multiple widgets) with a stateless widget, and then wrap it with FutureBuilder.

Comment: Thank you so much. I use future builder and it works .

Comment: @KeeRushar Please mark the solution as answer if it helps. Thanks!